# How to connect Android Studio with SQL Server database?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database, connection

We are currently having the same problem as here: [How to connect Android Studio with SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938140/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-sql-server-database/34967509), but it hasn't been answered.

We also succeeded the connection on Eclipse, using the `sqljdb4.jar` file, we tried on android the same code as in Eclipse, but it works only on Eclipse.

We also tried another driver, `jtds1.3.1.jar`, but it didn't work either

We replaced the login and password by x and y ;)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flux_sequence);

    String url = "jdbc:jtdc:sqlserver://vps342074.ovh.net/IZY309";
    //String url = "jdbc:jtdc:sqlserver://vps342074.ovh.net/MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=IZY309";
    //String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://vps342074.ovh.net\\MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=IZY309";
    String user = "x";
    String pass = "y";

    try {
        //TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCol5);
        //textViewToChange.setText("Hello");
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("SELECT CATEGORIE FROM dbo.PPROFIL WHERE CATEGORIE = 'ac' ");
        while (resultat.next()) {

            String result = resultat.getString(1);
            TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCol5);
            textViewToChange.setText(result);
            Log.d("My Custom Tag", result);


        }resultat.close();
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void close(Connection con) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    close(con);

}
```

Here are the returned errors :

```
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:186)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at 
com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence.flux_sequence.onCreate(flux_sequence.java:32)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: how exactly all of what you tried doesn't work? It crashes? gives exceptions? If it does, where is the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Your URL is of wrong format. The correct one should be `String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[SERVER_ADDRESS]/[DB_NAME]";`

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
@Prerak Sola : 
This syntax doesn't change anything we think, but we have the following errors to begin (@Vlad Matvienko) :
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:186)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
02-15 14:34:01.896 4180-4180/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence 
Do you have some advices?

Comment: @mhyeah You are missing the `jtds` part in the URL which specifies the driver. It won't work without that. Also I do not see in the code anything regarding the driver's registration, something like `Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`.

Comment: We just add the returned errors in the post. If you see other problems.

When we add your line in the "try" loop, it returns an unhanded exception : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

What do you think? Than you, really

Comment: The main problem is that Android Studio returns "not suitable driver"...

Comment: Try removing the `newInstance()` part.

Comment: Also what is your db server URL?

Comment: It returns the same unhandled error when we remove the newInstance() part. And our db server URL is : vps342074.ovh.net

Answer (score 5):

Before you make connection, you must add 2 lines of code:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Complete code as: (may be)

```
package com.ipvsoft.sendsms.utility;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class SQLConnection {
    private static final String LOG = "DEBUG";
    private static String ip = "192.168.3.85";
    private static String port = "1433";
    private static String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String db = "THTData";
    private static String un = "sa";
    private static String password = "admin";
    public static Connection connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip +":"+port+";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d(LOG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(LOG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is because you are missing the line `Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");`

Add it before establishing the database connection, so it will look something like this in your code:

```
String url = "jdbc:jtdc:sqlserver://vps342074.ovh.net/IZY309";
try {
    //TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCol5);
    //textViewToChange.setText("Hello");
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("SELECT CATEGORIE FROM dbo.PPROFIL WHERE CATEGORIE = 'ac' ");
    while (resultat.next()) {

        String result = resultat.getString(1);
        TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCol5);
        textViewToChange.setText(result);
        Log.d("My Custom Tag", result);
    }
    resultat.close();
    statement.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure with the "jdbc:jtdc" in the URL and the "jtds.jdbc" in the Class.forName() ?

Comment: Ok. We did it, but it also returns "no suitable driver". Maybe do you have other ideas?

Comment: Could you please update your question with the latest code?

Comment: Have you successfully added the JAR to your project? The error might be due to that too.

Comment: There is also this red error : 
02-15 15:33:14.181 28899-28899/com.example.gaetan.fluxsequence E/ViewSystem: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.

Comment: To add the JAR, we drag the file in the "libs" part, and after a right click on the file : "add as library". It creates the compile line in the gradle (app). Is it enough?