# Android using mssql server

Tags: android, sql, sql-server-2008, mssql-jdbc

How to retrieve data from mssql using android studio display data in edit text box.. But I am all ready connect mssql and Android studio but don't retrieve data from data base pls send source code???

Comment: What have you done this far? Can you share your code? In what point you fail?

Comment: Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247465/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-sql-server-database
or: http://www.parallelcodes.com/connect-android-to-ms-sql-database-2/

Comment: I don't know any source code for retrieve in mssql  @pirho

Comment: I am already connect my app and change activity  I need only source code for retrieve data only...    @tuan huynh