# Connection Class for connecting android studio to sql server database

Tags: android, sql-server, database, database-connection

I'm a beginner in android.
For developing I use Android studio 3.1.
I'd like to connect one of my application, to sql server, but i'm not able to find any working connection class.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Please have a look :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247465/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

there is no support to thing like this 
in this case, you need to build an API to communicate between Android and SQL server