# How To Connect SQL Server to Android Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, android-studio

How can I connect my Android studio project to SQL database

Should I do something in the database to make it local so I can connect it to the database

Comment: I think this link will help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247465/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-sql-server-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247465/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-sql-server-database)

Comment: you can do something like this if the database is hosted online and you can connect directly over the internet. A more conventional architecture though would be to put a web API in between the app and the database, and have the app talk to the API instead. It's usually a bit more secure for one thing. But SQL Server itself will not run on an Android platform, if that's what you're asking. If you need a database which actually resides on the device there will be other alternatives you can search for (although I am not, personally, familiar with them).